# Total Possible Paths in a Square Grid when diagonal movement is allowed

Tags: combinatorics

How should I answer this-"Compute the total number of possible paths from (0,0) to (7,9) if the steps R (to the right) and U (up) are allowed, along with the diagonal step D:(x,y)→(x +1,y+ 1)"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you need a program to compute that? Do you want to do it by hand?

Comment: Léopold Houdin- Yes, I wish to compute it by hand.

Comment: Then, you'd have more chance over there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics.
In stackoverflow, people will mostly help you if you need help with programming related stuff...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** added calculation for arbitrary cell, not only diagonal one.

The number of ways on square grid is known as [Delannoy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number), for (n,n) cell sequence is `1, 3, 13, 63, 321, 1683, 8989...`

There is simple natural recurrence

```
D(m, n) = D(m-1, n) + D(m, n-1) + D(m-1,n-1)
```

that might be used to calculate values rather quickly for reasonable argument values (table approach, O(nm) operations including long summation).

"Closed formula"

```
D(m, n) = Sum[k=0..min(n, m)] {C(m + n - k, m) * C(m, k)}
```

for effective implementations requires table of binomial coefficients

```
#2D table quadratic approach
def PathsInSqGrid(n, m):
    D =  [[0 for x in range(m+1)] for y in range(n+1)]
    for i in range(n+1):
        D[i][0] = 1
    for i in range(m+1):
        D[0][i] = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1,m+1):
            D[i][j] = D[i][j-1] + D[i-1][j] + D[i-1][j-1]
    return D[n][m]

def NCr(n, k):
    result = 1
    if k > n - k:
        k = n - k
    for i  in range (1, k + 1):
       result = (result * (n - i + 1)) // i
    return result

#closed formula
def PathsCF(n, m):
    #D(m, n) = Sum[k=0..min(n, m)] {C(m + n - k, m) * C(m, k)}
    res = 0
    for k in range(0, min(n, m) + 1):
       res += NCr(m + n - k, m) *NCr(m, k)
    return res

print(PathsInSqGrid(7, 9))
print(PathsCF(7, 9))
>>> 
224143
224143
```

Wiki also shows two so-called "closed formulas" for central Delannoy numbers (while I believe that closed formula should be single expression without loop of length n):

```
D(n) = Sum[k=0..n]{C(n,k)*C(n+k,k)}
D(n) = Sum[k=0..n]{C(n,k)^2 * 2^n}
```

and recurrence (looks simple, linear complexity, but real implementation requires division of long number by short one)

```
n*D(n) = 3*(2*n-1) * D(n-1) - (n-1)*D(n-2)
```

and generating function

```
Sum[n=0..Inf]{D(n)*x^n} = 1/Sqrt(1 - 6 * x + x^2) = 1 + 3x + 13x^2 + 63x^3 +...
```

Code

```
#central Delannoy numbers

#2D table quadratic approach
#linear approach for diagonal cell (n,n)

def PathsInSqGridLin(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 2 * n + 1
    A, B = 1, 3
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        B, A = (3 * (2 * i - 1) * B - (i - 1) * A) // i,  B
    return B

print(PathsInSqGridLin(3))
print(PathsInSqGridLin(100))
>>
63
2053716830872415770228778006271971120334843128349550587141047275840274143041
```